# Can some one please tell me what this code is doing and what its outputting, please

Tags: javascript, titanium

I think this code is getting every image that has a filename without @2x and doing something with it. Can someone explain what the code is doing and what its output is.

```
var icnPath = 'images/icons/bundle/';
var path = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, icnPath);
var dir = path.getDirectoryListing();
var images = [];

for (intFile in dir) {
    if (dir[intFile].indexOf("@2x") == -1) {
        images[dir[intFile].replace(".png", "")] = icnPath + dir[intFile];  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes ,
the code is getting files from  Resource directory under iconpath which have names without @2x. And removing .png extension from images to get array of image names in given path.

your  images [] will be look like

```
images['iconA']='images/icons/bundle/iconA.png';
images['iconB']='images/icons/bundle/iconB.png';
images['iconC']='images/icons/bundle/iconC.png';
```

Comment: Great thats been a real help, any ideas on this?

`var imageOffset = (images.hasOwnProperty(data.classes[data.classes.length-1])) ? data.classes[data.classes.length-1] : "home";`

Comment: imageOffset is getting images class Name property if there exist any ,otherwise set it as "home"

Comment: if your question is answered ,please mark it as answered. It may be helpful for someone in future

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `Ti` is, but looks like it's going through all files in a directory, and populating the array `images` as if it were an associated array/object with all files that DO NOT have "@2x" in their file name, resulting in a hash with the filename, stripped of the extension, and the value of the path.

```
images: {
  'filename1': 'images/icons/bundle/filename1.png',
  'filename2': 'images/icons/bundle/filename2.png',
   ...
}
```

Comment: ah i see, i am also unsure of this:

`var imageOffset = (images.hasOwnProperty(data.classes[data.classes.length-1])) ? data.classes[data.classes.length-1] : "home";`